# building a c++ project with customly built gcc(g++)

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I have built gcc-4.8.2 from source code, configured with --prefix=.../destdir. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

So after I ran 'make' and 'make install' all the libraries where built and put to

> .../destdir/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2.

And I also have newly built g++ and gcc in

> .../destdir/bin

the question is, if I try to build a program with .../destdir/bin/g++ will use the newly made libraries when linking, or the ones located in standard paths?

If latter, what is the best way to make it linkt against the new ones, or is there a way to know what libs are used?

Answer (score 0):

By default it will use the right libraries at link time, *but not at run time*.

To use the right libraries at run time, either add `-Wl,-rpath=/absolute/path/to/your/libraries` to your link command (recommended), or add that directory to your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH (a quick-and-dirty workaround).